# Rounding floating point program

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm trying to write a C program to find the smallest positive integer x so that (1/x) * x is not equal to 1, using single precision. And I do it again with double precision. I know that the x for single precision is 41, however when I test it by writing C code, I still get 1.00000

This is my test code

```
int main()
{
    float x = 41;
    float div = 1/x;
    float test = div * x;

    printf("%f\n", test);
}
```

I get 1.0000 instead of a 0.999999

Comment: please see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html - they are just a representation of a number

Comment: @EdHeal how do I get the 0.999999 value?

Comment: @jqdc2224, try `printf("%.10f\n", test);`

Comment: The smallest positive integer is 1. (1/1) * 1 = 1. Why would x/x ever not be one for a real number other than 0?

Comment: You math is strange because _1/x * x_ will be 1 anyway. What exactly are you trying to find out? Float precision? If so, read that document posted in the comment above

Comment: I think (i may be wrong) the person is trying to find out the limitations of floating point numbers. But that depends on processor/compiler/,...

Comment: @EdHeal in that case the document you posted is a must read :-)

Comment: @EdHeal Yes sorry I am trying to find floating point precision

Comment: There are others to limit errors in calculations as well

Comment: @EdHeal the .10f\n did the trick!! thanks @R Sahu, I will read that article

Comment: @jqdc2224 - Please read it at least twice and understand the consequences.

Comment: @EdHeal I will, thanks again! Also before I read it could you tell me how I would convert the floating point to double precision?

Comment: Change the keyword `float` in your program to `double`. You will need to look up the format for `printf`. I have not used that for years - C++ now

Comment: Be careful, compiler may very likely optimize away all your code.

Comment: I bet you did not get "1.0000", but "1.000000".  Exactness in posting helps.  Try `printf("%e\n", 1.0 - test);` instead to see difference from 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing the problem using

```
printf("%f\n", test);
```

since the default precision used by `printf` for floating point numbers is `6`. If you increase the precision to `10`, you will see that the number is not `1.0`.

```
printf("%.10f\n", test);
```

prints `0.9999999404` for me.